Type error: No overload matches this call
I am getting this error
Overload 1 of 2, '(action: (state: { errors: { image_url?: string[] | undefined; bookid?: string[] | undefined; shelf?: string[] | undefined; title?: string[] | undefined; author?: string[] | undefined; publication_year?: string[] | undefined; ... 4 more ...; total_copies?: string[] | undefined; }; message: string; } | { ...; }) => { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | Promise<...>, initialState: { ...; } | { ...; }, permalink?: string | undefined): [state: ...]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(prevState: [State], formData: FormData) => Promise<{ errors: { image_url?: string[] | undefined; bookid?: string[] | undefined; shelf?: string[] | undefined; title?: string[] | undefined; ... 6 more ...; total_copies?: string[] | undefined; }; message: string; } | { ...; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: { errors: { image_url?: string[] | undefined; bookid?: string[] | undefined; shelf?: string[] | undefined; title?: string[] | undefined; author?: string[] | undefined; publication_year?: string[] | undefined; ... 4 more ...; total_copies?: string[] | undefined; }; message: string; } | { ...; }) => { ...; } |...'.
      Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(action: (state: { errors: { image_url?: string[] | undefined; bookid?: string[] | undefined; shelf?: string[] | undefined; title?: string[] | undefined; author?: string[] | undefined; publication_year?: string[] | undefined; ... 4 more ...; total_copies?: string[] | undefined; }; message: string; } | { ...; }, payload: FormData) => { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | Promise<...>, initialState: { ...; } | { ...; }, permalink?: string | undefined): [state: ...]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(prevState: [State], formData: FormData) => Promise<{ errors: { image_url?: string[] | undefined; bookid?: string[] | undefined; shelf?: string[] | undefined; title?: string[] | undefined; ... 6 more ...; total_copies?: string[] | undefined; }; message: string; } | { ...; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: { errors: { image_url?: string[] | undefined; bookid?: string[] | undefined; shelf?: string[] | undefined; title?: string[] | undefined; author?: string[] | undefined; publication_year?: string[] | undefined; ... 4 more ...; total_copies?: string[] | undefined; }; message: string; } | { ...; }, payload: Form...'.
      Types of parameters 'prevState' and 'state' are incompatible.
        Type '{ errors: { image_url?: string[] | undefined; bookid?: string[] | undefined; shelf?: string[] | undefined; title?: string[] | undefined; author?: string[] | undefined; publication_year?: string[] | undefined; ... 4 more ...; total_copies?: string[] | undefined; }; message: string; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type '[State]'.
          Type '{ errors: { image_url?: string[] | undefined; bookid?: string[] | undefined; shelf?: string[] | undefined; title?: string[] | undefined; author?: string[] | undefined; publication_year?: string[] | undefined; ... 4 more ...; total_copies?: string[] | undefined; }; message: string; }' is not assignable to type '[State]'.

  10 | export default function Form() {
  11 |   const initialState: State = { message: null, errors: {} };
> 12 |   const [State, formAction] = useActionState(createBook, initialState);
     |                                              ^
  13 |   return (
  14 |     <form action={formAction}>
  15 |       <div className="rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-4 md:p-6">
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

Create Book Form
// create-form.tsx
"use client";

import { createBook, State } from '@/app/lib/book-actions';
import { useActionState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { bookFormFields } from '@/app/lib/book-form-fields';
import { Button } from '@/app/ui/button';

export default function Form() {
  const initialState: State = { message: null, errors: {} };
  const [State, formAction] = useActionState(createBook, initialState);
  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
      <div className="rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-4 md:p-6">
        {bookFormFields.map((field) => (
          <div className="mb-4" key={field.id}>
            <label htmlFor={field.id} className="mb-2 block text-sm font-medium">
              {field.label}
            </label>
            <div className="relative mt-2 rounded-md">
              {field.type === "checkbox" ? (
                <input
                  id={field.id}
                  name={field.id}
                  type="checkbox"
                  className="peer block h-5 w-5 rounded border-gray-200 text-blue-600 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-200"
                  aria-describedby={`${field.id}-error`}
                />
              ) : (
                <input
                  id={field.id}
                  name={field.id}
                  type={field.type}
                  placeholder={field.placeholder}
                  className="peer block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-2 px-3 text-sm placeholder-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-200"
                  aria-describedby={`${field.id}-error`}
                />
              )}
            </div>
            <div id={`${field.id}-error`} aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
              {State.errors?.[field.id] &&
                State.errors[field.id].map((error: string) => (
                  <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-red-500" key={error}>
                    {error}
                  </p>
                ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="mt-6 flex justify-end gap-4">
        <Link
          href="/dashboard/invoices"
          className="flex h-10 items-center rounded-lg bg-gray-100 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-600 transition-colors hover:bg-gray-200"
        >
          Cancel
        </Link>
        <Button type="submit">Create Book</Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}


This is my create Book actions
'use server';
import { z } from 'zod';
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { signIn } from '@/auth';
import { AuthError } from 'next-auth';

// Define the schema for form validation using Zod
const FormSchema = z.object({
    id: z.string(),
    bookid: z.string({
        invalid_type_error: "Please enter a library book id",
    }),
    shelf: z.string({
        invalid_type_error: "Please enter a library book shelf",
    }),
    title: z.string({
        invalid_type_error: "Please enter a library book title",
    }),
    author: z.string({
        invalid_type_error: "Please enter a library book author",
    }),
    publication_year: z.number({
        invalid_type_error: "Please enter a library book publication year",
    }),
    genre: z.string({
        invalid_type_error: "Please enter a library book genre",
    }),
    price: z.coerce.number()
        .gt(0, { message: 'Please enter an amount greater than 0.' }),
    language: z.string({
        invalid_type_error: "Please enter a library book language",
    }),
    image_url: z.string({
        invalid_type_error: "Please enter a library book image URL",
    }),
    in_stock: z.boolean(),
    total_copies: z.number(),
    date: z.string(),
});


export async function authenticate(
    prevState: { message: string },
    formData: FormData,
) {
    try {
        await signIn('credentials', formData);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof AuthError) {
            switch (error.type) {
                case 'CredentialsSignin':
                    return 'Invalid credentials.';
                default:
                    return 'Something went wrong.';
            }
        }
        throw error;
    }
}


const CreateBook = FormSchema.omit({ id: true, date: true });
const UpdateBook = FormSchema.omit({ id: true, date: true });

// Define the structure for the state
export type State = {
    errors?: {
        bookid?: string[];
        shelf?: string[];
        title?: string[];
        author?: string[];
        publication_year?: number[];
        genre?: string[];
        price?: number[];
        language?: string[];
        image_url?: string[];
        in_stock?: boolean[];
        total_copies?: number[];
    };
    message?: string | null;
};

export async function createBook(prevState: [State], formData: FormData) {
    // Validate form using Zod
    const validatedFields = CreateBook.safeParse({
        bookid: formData.get('bookid'),
        shelf: formData.get('shelf'),
        title: formData.get('title'),
        author: formData.get('author'),
        publication_year: Number(formData.get('publication_year')),
        genre: formData.get('genre'),
        price: Number(formData.get('price')),
        language: formData.get('language'),
        image_url: formData.get('image_url'),
        in_stock: Boolean(formData.get('in_stock')),
        total_copies: Number(formData.get('total_copies')),
    });

    // If form validation fails, return errors early. Otherwise, continue.
    if (!validatedFields.success) {
        return {
            errors: validatedFields.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
            message: 'Missing Fields. Failed to Create Book.',
        };
    }

    // Prepare data for insertion into the database
    const { bookid,
        shelf,
        title,
        author,
        publication_year,
        genre,
        price,
        language,
        image_url,
        in_stock,
        total_copies } = validatedFields.data;
    const date = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

    // Insert data into the database
    try {
        await sql`
        INSERT INTO books (
        bookid,
        shelf,
        title,
        author,
        publication_year,
        genre,
        price,
        language,
        image_url,
        in_stock,
        total_copies)
        VALUES (
        ${bookid},
        ${shelf},
        ${title},
        ${author},
        ${publication_year},
        ${genre},
        ${price},
        ${language},
        ${image_url},
        ${in_stock},
        ${total_copies})
      `;
    } catch (error) {
        // If a database error occurs, return a more specific error.
        return {
            message: 'Database Error: Failed to Create Book.',
        };
    }

    // Revalidate the cache for the books page and redirect the user.
    revalidatePath('/dashboard/books');
redirect('/dashboard/books');
}

I am getting state error while buiding this NextJS 14 applicatio.

The type of the useActionState state is State since that's the type of initialState and that's the return type of createBook. Thus this should also be the input type of createBook, instead of [State].
So try changing
export async function createBook(prevState: [State], formData: FormData) {

to
export async function createBook(prevState: State, formData: FormData) {

